# How can I save a file with different names on each iteration in a loop? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, save, eval

I have a file that on each iteration in a loop changes the name, and i want to save it on each iteration with the name that he have on this iteratio. It's possible? How can i do it?

```
%matrixImages is a 3D matrix that on each iteration has different values
for i=1:N    
      cmd = ['images' num2str(i) '= matrixImages;'];
      eval(cmd); %now in images1 is the content of matrixImages
      save %i want to save images1 with the name images1,images2 with the name images2...
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,with the comand eval

```
 cmd = ['images' num2str(i) '= matrixImages;'];
 eval(cmd);
 eval(['save images' num2str(i) 'images' num2str(i) ';']);
```